# TideSDK | Bundle packaging

Tags: tidesdk

I have developed a TideSDK application and am now ready to package it, but I'm having problems with the network type installer.

It always gives me code 404 on the Application first run:

> Could not query info: Invalid HTTP Status Code (404)

I presume the installer is having difficulty with reaching the correct servers and downloading the needed runtime, but I have run through most solutions on this forum, and none have worked.

So I tried a bundle packaging, as it should include such runtime, but I must be doing something wrong, since it does not bundle within the MSI.
The code I'm executing is as follows:

> C:\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.2.0.RC6d\tibuild.py -p --type=BUNDLE --os=win32 "C:\path_to_app\app_dir"

I also tried:

> C:\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.2.0.RC6d\tibuild.py -p -t bundle --os=win32 "C:\path_to_app\app_dir"

And all the uppercase/lowercase combinations. Also tried version 1.2.0.4, without sucess. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the network type installer is not available anymore, since appcelerator has canceled their services for titanium desktop.

So you can only do bundle packaging. Try the following command:

```
python tibuild.py --dest=. --type=bundle --package=. "c:\path\to\your\app\dir"
```

This should build and package your app and create a installer for it.
Change "dest" and "package" to the directories where you want to have the built app and installation package.

You can omit the OS parameter, since the builder can only generate builds for the current OS.

Comment: Thanks @Christian Engel you're a life saver :) I was able to build it.. the only issue was that the folder I set up as the --package one, was empty, but the MSI was created with success in the --dest one.

Comment: Also, this doc might be helpful http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/packaging

Comment: @Christian Engel, Please give me an example. what i have to write instead of --dest=. and --package=.

Comment: I highly recommend not to use titanium anymore, its dangerously outdated.

But anyways: the dot in the command means "this directory". So you have to navigate your console to the directory where your compiled application should be stored, or replace the dot with a directory name.