# TideSDK invalid syntax error in tibuild.py

Tags: python, tidesdk

I am trying to bundle my app with TideSDK following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348035/tidesdk-bundle-packaging). My command is:

```
python tibuild.py --dest=hi --type=bundle --package=hi2 c:\users\name\desktop\test
```

It is giving me this error:

```
File "tibuild.py", line 39
  print "signal caught: %d" % signum
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Line 39 in tibuild.py says this:

```
print "signal caught: %d" % signum
```

I am using Python 3.2.3 with TideSDK 1.2.0 RC4 on Windows 7 64-bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have python 2.7 on your system and recommend you stay there for the time being. Scons is the build system we use for TideSDK. It may eventually be ported to python 3.x. since it is a very popular cross platform build system used by many large projects.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, `print` is a function. Use `print("signal caught: %d" % signum)`

Comment: Ok, this thing is riddled with this error. I changed them all and it compiles, but give me errors at lines like this:
`raise Exception(u'Could not find SDK version %s' % version)`

Comment: except Exception as e: and then you raise e. Python3 syntax.

Comment: What about this one `print u'    -> %s' % text`

Comment: First, this was not written by me. But, i am pretty sure it was written for Python 2, as v3 hasn't been out that long.

Comment: use 2to3 to convert that script to 3 syntax and then run it against python3.